# askopenfilename doesn't work for files in library folder

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, tkinter, bug-reporting

I'm trying to make a UI that requires selecting pictures, so I decided to use askopenfilename to get the path, but when I run this code.

```
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilenames
files = askopenfilenames()
print "Files:",files
```

and go to my "Pictures" library it prints out (' ',)

However if I go to the pictures folder through the "This PC" button then it prints out a proper file path.

A search found [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue18877) bug report but it seems to be closed and old yet still not fixed. Does anyone know a solution or if there's any intent to fix this? I'm running Python 2.7 and Windows 10.

Comment: You're saying that you open the dialog, select a file, click "ok", and then it prints `('',)`?

Comment: Yes. That bug report says basically the same thing. It seems to only be on windows.

Comment: It works correctly in 3.5 and 3.6. Depending on the underlying problem, there may be little hope of seeing this problem fixed in 2.7.